# Adjective refers to one word only or to more words

Tags: comma-splices

Please consider the next case:
1) Financial structure and policy.
2) Financial structure, and policy.
Can case (1) be read as "Financial structure and financial policy."?
Does "Financial" in case (2) refers only to "structure"?
Thank you.

Comment: Ultimately, both cases are ambiguous, I think.

Comment: This is not a comma splice.

Comment: Complete sentences, especially with the surrounding sentences, are usually very helpful with questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Yes

2.) No. The comma inserted breaks your sentence, but also unites two independent clauses.

*..upon reading the financial structure, and policy, for the transmission mechanism for the International Bank of Settlements...*

The comma is definitely not required however.

Comment: +1 Good example. I think the parenthetical commas strengthen the reading *policy* as *financial policy*, compared to the case without the commas.

Comment: I don't see even _one_ independent clause in either of the examples--the one in the question or the one here.